# Best model for social activity stream?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Our company is evaluating Neo4J as the database of choice for our social network. Our main requirement is a high performance social activity stream (reads eclipse writes). In modeling our data we independently designed what you call the Graphity model, which scales well, but is limited by Neo's max relationship types (~32,700).

Is there a way to increase the # of relationship types in order to use Graphity at scale?

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-cookbook-graphity.html
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-cookbook-newsfeed.html

Comment: +1 @Greg thanks for the link, I´m just in the same journey of how ho model an activity stream, good luck and let me know if you find something interesting

Answer (score 0):

If the number of relationships types is a concern, keep in mind that Neo4j supports properties on relationships.

So instead of `MATCH p=me-[:jane_knows*]->friend ....` you chould have something modeled like:

```
MATCH me-[jk:who_knows]->friend WHERE jk.who = 'jane'
```

That could effectively make all of you x_knows relationships into one relationship type with a property.  I am not sure if that would yield the same semantic or performance benefits of your use-case, but it is a possible solution to your concern.

Comment: Very interesting. I didn't think to use a property on an edge. At first glance it sounds like it would switch the query burden to Lucene since every relationship query becomes a Lucene index hit. I'll try it out and report back. Thank you!